# Converting Oracle date arithmetic to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, datetime

I have this Oracle query:

```
select sm.*
from MESSAGES sm
where sm.delivery_finished = 0
  and (sm.last_sent_date is null or (SYSDATE - sm.last_sent_date) * 24 * 60 * 60 > sm.delay)
  and sm.status = 'REQUEST_READY'
order by nvl(sm.last_sent_date, to_date('2000.01.01', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

How can I rewrite this query for PostgreSQL?

I tried this:

```
select sm.*
from MESSAGES sm
where sm.delivery_finished = 0
  and (sm.last_sent_date is null or (now() - sm.last_sent_date) * 24 * 60 * 60 > sm.delay)
  AND sm.status = 'REQUEST_READY'
order by COALESCE(sm.last_sent_date, to_date('2000.01.01', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

But on this line:

```
now() - sm.last_sent_date) * 24 * 60 * 60 > sm.delay
```

I get error:

> [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: interval > integer
>   Hint: An operator with the given name and types of arguments was not found. Perhaps you should add explicit type conversions. Position: 148

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do time subtraction, I would use [EXTRACT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function.

```
EXTRACT(SECOND FROM now() - sm.last_sent_date)  * 24 * 60 * 60 > sm.delay
```

We can see `now()- '2000.01.01'::timestamp` will return `interval` not the interger.

so `EXTRACT` function can help get the amount from time subtraction

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  now()- '2000.01.01'::timestamp,
        EXTRACT(SECOND FROM now() - '2000.01.01'::timestamp)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/21914/0)**:

```
|                                                ?column? | date_part |
|---------------------------------------------------------|-----------|
| 0 years 0 mons 6852 days 8 hours 47 mins 37.710379 secs | 37.710379 |
```

Comment: yes it helped! what about `order by nvl(sm.last_sent_date, to_date('2000.01.01', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))`?

Comment: @ip696 You can try to use `COALESCE`, There is a typo in your `order by COLEASCE(sm.last_sent_date, to_date('2000.01.01', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))` currently

Comment: [42883] ERROR: the coleasce function (timestamp without time zone, date) does not exist. Hint: The function with the given name and argument types was not found. Perhaps you should add explicit type conversions. Position: 231

Comment: Your `COLEASCE` is a typo ..  use `COALESCE` instead of `COLEASCE`

Comment: I write like this:`order by CASE sm.last_sent_date
           WHEN null THEN to_date('2000.01.01', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
           ELSE sm.last_sent_date
    END
` Is this a normal way?

Comment: @ip696 No problem glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

As the error says:

> operator does not exist: interval> integer

You have to typecast explicitly one of the two arguments.
In PostgreSQL you can use ::desired_type to cast the column.

I guess in your case you have to add **::integer** after the closing bracket